# Mac suddenly reporting all my disks as full

Tags: macos, mac

I should have several hundred gigabytes free. It even reports my sparsebundles mounted manually as full.

I have the newest OS X version. I am more or less at a complete loss for the reason - Google does not seem to reveal a reason.

The best guess I have is my gf started syncing her iphone with icloud / account on the mac - but as far as I can tell that's like a few hundred pictures. (It also does no explain why a sparsebundle is being reported as full - and why it makes zero difference deleting gigabytes in the sparsebundle.)

Comment: Mac was using 380 gigabyte on logs in "/cores" https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215410/os-x-el-capitan-cores-directory-taking-up-a-lot-of-space

Comment: Try using some software like [Grand Perspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/) to get an overview where is the files/folders using up all the spaces.